# HTTP response not being parsed as string array

Tags: angular

I am using Angular and am trying to make an HTTP call and interpret the response as a string array. The call is made, but an HTTP error is thrown. Please help me get this working properly.

function

```
getOrgSuggestions(query: string): Observable<string[]> {
     console.log('Calling service to get linktypes');
     return this.httpClient.get<string[]>(this.orgUrl + query);
   }
```

sample HTTP response when I use curl

```
["university of texas austin","university of arizona"]
```

Error I see on web console

```
error: error { target: XMLHttpRequest, isTrusted: true, lengthComputable: false, … }
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map(0) }
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:7001/suggest/tyler/a: 0 Unknown Error"
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "http://localhost:7001/suggest/tyler/a"
<prototype>: Object { … }
```

Comment: This might be related to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS). You can solve this by setting up a proxy: https://angular.io/guide/build "Proxying to a backend server"

Answer (score 1):

@Peter Bagyinszki was correct

I needed to add the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *` to the response from my server at `localhost:7001`. Now everything is working